# Error in + operator overloading

Tags: c++

```
class Array
{
private:

int siz;
int *ptr;

public:
// constructos, setters, getters, and other functions.


void operator+(int x)                           // Addition operator
{
Array temp(siz+1);

for(int i = 0; i<temp.size; i++)
{
    temp.ptr[i] = ptr[i];
    if(i == temp.siz -1)
        temp.ptr[i] = x;
}

deallocate();

siz = temp.siz;
ptr = new int[siz];
for(int i= 0; i<siz;i++)
{
    ptr[i] = temp.ptr[i];
}

delete [] temp.ptr;
temp.ptr = NULL;
};

//GLOBAL FUNCTUONS

ostream &operator<< (ostream &o,Array A)
 {
for(int i = 0; i < A.siz; i++)
{
    out << A.ptr[i] << " ";
}
o << endl;
return out;
}

istream &operator>> (istream &in, Array &A)
{
int val;
for(int i=0; i<S.siz; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter value at S["<<i<<"]: ";
    cin >> value;
    A.setter(i,val);
}
return in;
}



int main()
{
 Array A1(2);
cin >> A1;
cout << A1 + 4;
}
```

The compiler gives an error of:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:476:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, char __c)

note:   cannot convert ‘S2.Set::operator+(4)’ (type ‘void’) to type ‘char’
  **cout << S2 + 4;**
```

I have friend functions for the ostream/istream inside class. 
               ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to print the return value of the `operator+`, but there isn't one. It's return type is `void`, and how can you print a `void`?

Make your `operator+` return a reference to the object:

```
Array& operator+(int x) {
    // ...
    return *this; // reference to self
}
```

But note that it seems kind of strange to use `+` to indicate appending to an existing array. `+` usually means "combine these two things and give me back the result". For instance, `2+3` is `5`, but it doesn't try to change the value of `2` into `5`. That just doesn't make sense.

You *can* use `operator+` the way you do, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Perhaps you could instead call it `append()`, or `insert()`?

---

Also, you have a bug:

```
Array temp(siz+1);

for(int i = 0; i<temp.size; i++)
{
    temp.ptr[i] = ptr[i]; // <------- HERE
    if(i == temp.siz -1)
        temp.ptr[i] = x;
}
```

In the marked line, you access one-past-the-end of the original array. Instead, iterate up to `this->siz`, and then assign the last element in the new array separately:

```
Array temp(this->siz+1);

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < this->siz; +i)
{
    temp.ptr[i] = this->ptr[i];
}
temp.ptr[this->siz] = x;
```

(And what's with calling it `siz`? That's just confusing, it looks like a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+` returns `void`.  When you use

```
cout << A1 + 4;
```

You can actually write it like

```
cout << A1.operator+(4);
```

Now you can see that what we are trying to output is the return of the call to `operator+(4)`.  Since it is `void` it is going to fail as we cannot output a void.  YOu need to have `operator+` either return a reference to the object or return a temporary by value.